# Populate a javascript array shorthand for keys like php

Tags: javascript, arrays, shorthand, array-key

In Javascript, know I can set an array so that the key is a autonumbered (starting at 0) assigned array:

```
var d_names = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
              "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

// Key for Sunday is '0'
```

and if I want to assign keys, I could do:

```
    var d_names={};
    d_names[5]="Sunday";
    d_names[6]="Monday";
    d_names[7]="Tuesday";
    d_names[8]="Wednesday";
    d_names[9]="Thursday";
    d_names[10]="Friday";
    d_names[11]="Saturday";

    // Key for Sunday is '5'
```

But is there a shorthand way to assign the keys like in PHP?

```
var d_names = new Array(5=>"Sunday", 6=>"Monday", 7=>"Tuesday", 8=>"Wednesday", 
            9=>"Thursday", 10=>"Friday", 11=>"Saturday"); 

// Doesn't work
```

Comment: why you want start your index from 5?

Comment: Javascript does not support associative arrays. You can use, however, an object. Albeit the syntax is different.

Comment: To whoever had reviewed the suggested edit: please don't approve it as is, if it overwrites changes from a later edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is an object:

```
var d_names = {
    5: "Sunday",
    6: "Monday"
    //...
};
```

You can then get `"Sunday"` like this:

```
var sunday = d_names[5];
```

Comment: Javascript does not support Associative Arrays... that's an object!

Comment: True, I'm updating my answer. Since JavaScript objects can be _used_ as associative arrays, it's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Okay, I understand!  Then, `answer=d_names[5]` (if it were an associative array), what would be the javascript equivalent syntax to get `answer` on key 5?

Comment: The same syntax. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: There is one small issue with this - it's not exactly the same thing as an Array. For example, it has no length property, and you can't push() new values onto the end. If you don't need these (or other) Array-specific features, then this is fine.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, an array with manually defined keys (as opposed to consecutive integers beginning with 0) is called an "associative array" - this is what you have in your example above with '=>' delimiting keys and values.

In Javascript, an "associative array" is technically an "object" (though everything in JS is an object - that's a more detailed topic though).

Shorthand for an "indexed array" (consecutive integer keys) in JS is:

```
var d_names = [
  'Sunday',
  'Monday',
  // etc.
];
```

whereas shorthand for an object (like an associative array) in JS is:

```
var d_names = {
  5: 'Sunday',
  6: 'Monday',
  // etc.
};
```

You should however be careful when using indexed arrays -vs- objects/associative in Javascript. Javascript is not PHP, and the fact that "everything is an object" has repercussions when looping. A notable difference is that `for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i){}` iterates over an arrays *keys* but `for(var x in obj) {}` iterates over an objects "members" which can differ depending on environment/browser/etc.

Answer (score 1):

The following in php:

```
echo json_encode(new Array(5=>"Sunday", 6=>"Monday", 7=>"Tuesday",...11=>"Saturday"));
```

Will produce JSON that looks like

```
   {"5":"Sunday","6":"Monday" , "7":"Tuesday"..."11":"Saturday"}
```

If sent via ajax and result is json parsed it will return an object:

```
 obj= { "5": "Sunday", "6": "Monday",....  "11": "Saturday"}
```

Now you can access using javascript object notation:

```
 alert( obj['5'] )/* SUnday*/
```

Comment: Your 2nd code block doesn't look right. You've fed in an associative array with string values but it's returning an indexed array with objects (with string values).

Comment: Ah, apologies. One more comment on your edit (I think you had this correct previously) - JSON is "stricter" than Javascript in that it doesn't allow integer keys - so PHP will output the keys wrapped in double-quotes. This is purely for JSON though, so somewhat irrelevant to the OP, but no harm mentioning it - it's tripped me up a lot in the past.

Comment: Really? You may have thought me something new... /goes off to research.

Comment: @lucideer  numbers are valid however as values. I never use numeric keys

Answer (score 1):

There are [no associative arrays](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/) in JavaScript. You have two choices:

A simple object, used as a (unsorted!) key-value map - easy to write as a literal, also JSON syntax:

```
{
    "5": "Sunday",
    "6": "Monday",
    "7": "Tuesday",
    "8": "Wednesday",
    "9": "Thursday",
    "10": "Friday",
    "11": "Saturday"    
}
```

Or you can use a sparse `Array`, i.e. with no values for the properties 0 to 4. You can easily create it via

```
var arr = new Array(5); // creates an empty array object with length 5
arr.push("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
```

which is equivalent to the literal

```
[,,,,, "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
```

Comment: very good link on the dangers of trying to use associative arrays in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly but you can use an Object

```
var obj = {

5:"Sunday",
6:"Monday",
7:"Tuesday",
8:"Wednesday",
9:"Thursday",
10:"Friday",
11:"Saturday"    
}
```

If want to use array

```
var arr = [];
arr[4] = undefined;
arr.push("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with this and some other tricks

```
 var d_names = [,,,,,"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
          "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

 alert(d_names[5]); //prints "Sunday"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  But this was more of a 'what if';  The days could have been names of pieces of fruit or something else.  I am using an index which may not be in numerical order.  I have just been fuzzy on the array vs. object thing, but some of the other answers have helped too.